# Copare value on List<Object> with other List and update other value without knowing Index

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist, compare

Let's just said I have a ArrayList of Objects, let's called `"Category"` (`List<Category>`) that it has:

```
get/setName
get/setImportance
get/setImage
```

Those values came from a web service (for now, get/setImportance is always 0, the server doesn't have this info)... But, in this way, the service have there own sort (non functional for the reason I need).

The user will have the chance to modify locally that "Importance" and sort it by those Importance positions.

Let's say:

-Server response Name:

```
*Name= Sports, Importance= 0
*Name= News, Importance= 0
*Name= Music, Importance= 0
*Name= Gaming, Importance= 0
```

-But the user gave the Importance (New local list save it on SharedPreference):

```
*Name= Gaming, Importance= 1
*Name= News, Importance= 2
*Name= Sports, Importance= 3
*Name= Music, Importance= 4
```

I need to update the server info (some of the values change every 3 hours) but I need to keep the user Important sort, so, every time he/she opens the app, they'll have the custom sorting.

I'll need to compare the ArrayList from the server with the local List on SharedPreference (could be a HashMap, List, don't care) and ".set" to update the value "Importance" of the original ArrayList by comparing the "Name" of both lists. I don't know the index in both cases.

What is the best way to do it? A "for" to copare values when matches? Using the Collections Comparator? Any other suggestions?

PS: Final sorted list should keep a List and not a HashMap or other... the entire app use this architecture and I move the List from Activity to Activity, that's why I need ".set" to update the value (again, I don't know the index).

Here is a potato for the weird long question

Comment: Can you give a unique identifier to your objects? Then you could have a map with that ID as the key, and update accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @SamBarnum... well... Name should never change, not sure with the Id, that I do have, could change... let's just said I delete by mistake the Category and the Id will change when add it again, but the Name will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the Category's `name` is unique, I would store the information as a HashMap:

```
HashMap<String, Category> map = HashMap<String, Category>();
for(Category c : response) { // assume response is List<Category>
    map.put(c.getName(), c);
}
```

As for the user's preference I would store as `List<String> userPreference;` containing the categories' name in the user's order. To build your `List<Category> categories;` you can:

```
List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();
for(String name : userPreference) {
    categories.add(map.get(name));
}
```

You will then have the `categories` object with the proper sorting.

Comment: Thanks for the response :) The storage list should have "Name=NameOfCategory, Importance=IntOfImportance" and the Origina/Final list have like 4 or 5 keys, the matches "keys" are 2, "Name" and "Importance", Name to compare and Importance to update the value. Names should match and update only Importance with the new Int.

Comment: Since Importance signifies the order of the categories, you can adjust the order of the names of categories in the userPreference list to reflect their Importance value.